# TV and PC power cords

Tags: power, cables

I have a Samsung PS43E450 TV (pic [here](http://www.tien21avila.com/media/catalog/product/s/a/samsung_4.jpg)). I lost the power cord. Can I just use the power cable from my PC (since it fits in the slot), or will it blow up?

Comment: Here's my suggestion on how to make this question *not* off-topic here. Ask it in the context of "Is there any difference in power cords that fit [this] type of socket?" or "Are all power cords that fit [this] socket configuration the same?" Then the question becomes relevant for electronics design, *and* helps you out with your TV. The answer should illustrate that the IEC connector is a standard, but that the other end may vary by region.

Comment: The general rule is that simple power leads are fine to swap. Power bricks are not ok to swap without carefully checking the specs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, no problem. That's the same connector.

There could be issues if you bought the TV in a country with different mains voltage. You'd have to check with the manual/label on the back if it works with the voltage of your current country then.

Answer (score 1):

That's a common IEC-60320 C13 socket. Any cable with a c14 plug at one end, and your local outlet type at the other will work. These are standard off the shelf cables.